# No errors but, my records aren't being added to my database

Tags: php, html, mysql, mysqli

I'm very new to PHP and MySQL, I've been working on this for three days, and this problem has me stumped. I get no errors and no query is added to my database. After the page register.php queues, it should load login.php with text saying `Registered`, but it is blank and no record are added to the database.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>

<?php

$page_title = 'Register';
if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST')
{
    include_once "connect.php";

    $errors = array();
    if( empty( $_POST['user_id']))
    {
        $errors[] = 'Enter your user ID.';
    }
    else
    {
        $ui = mysqli_real_escape_string($db_name, trim($_POST['user_id']));
    }
    if ( empty($POST['pass1']))
    {
        if($_POST['pass1'] != $_POST['pass2'])
        { 
            $errors[] = 'Passwords do not match.';
        }
        else
        {
            $fn = mysqli_real_escape_string($db_name, trim($_POST['pass1']));
        }
    }
    else
    {    
        $errors[] = 'Enter your Password.';
    }
    if (empty($errors))
    {
        $q = "INSERT INTO User_id
              (user,password)
              VALUES ('$ui','$fn',SHA('$fn'),NOW())";
        $r = mysqli_query ($db_name,$q);

        if ($r)
        {
            echo '<h1>Registered!</h1>

               <p> You are now registered.</p>
               <p><a href="login.php">Login</a></p>';
        }
        mysqli_close( $db_name);
        exit();                                
    }
    else 
    {
        echo '<h1>Error!</hl>
          <p id="err_msg">The following error(s) occurred:<br>';
        foreach ($errors as $msg)
        {
            echo "-$msg<br>";
        }
        echo 'Please try again.</p>';
        mysqli_close( $db_name);
    }
}
?>  

<h1>Register</h1>
<form action = "register.php" method="POST">
  <p>
   User ID: <input type="text" name= "user_id"
   value="<?php if (isset( $_POST[ 'user_id']))
      echo $_POST[ 'user_id'];?>">
   Password: <input type="password" name="pass1"
   value="<?php if (isset($_POST['pass1']))
      echo $_POST ['pass1'];?>">  
      Confirm Password: <input type="password" name="pass2"
      value="<?php if(isset($_POST['pass2']))
      echo $_POST['pass2'];?>">
  </p> <p>
  <input type="submit" value= "Register"> </p>
</form>      

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: There's no errors because you don't look for them. Try using mysqli_error() and see what you get.

Comment: `if ( empty($POST['pass1']))`..... don't you mean `if ( ! empty($POST['pass1']))` here?

Comment: If you properly indent your code, it will be much easier to spot if one of those many ifs is misplaced e.g.

Comment: Have you tried checking which part of your code executes and which one does not? That could give a clue where the problem lies (not very advanced debugging, but should give a clue :)).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is wrong:

```
$q = "INSERT INTO User_id (user,password)
        VALUES ('$ui','$fn',SHA('$fn'),NOW())";
```

Inserting 4 values for 2 columns is not going to work.

Add this to the top of your script so that mysqli will throw exceptions and tell you exactly what is wrong:

```
mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ALL);
```

Answer (score 6):

You're telling MySQL that you want to insert data into two columns but then give it four values to insert. That will cause an error. But you don't see it because you do not check [`mysqli_error()`](https://www.php.net/mysqli_error) after your query.

```
$q = "INSERT INTO User_id (user,password) VALUES ('$ui','$fn',SHA('$fn'),NOW())";
                             ^^^ 2 columns            ^^^ 4 values
```

Here's a *very basic* example of error handling:

```
$r = mysqli_query ($db_name,$q);
if ($r === false) {
    echo mysqli_error($db_name);
    exit; // This needs to be a lot better
}
```

Answer (score -2):

```
$q = "INSERT INTO User_id
              (user,password)
              VALUES ('$ui','$fn',SHA('$fn'),NOW())";
```

table columns are too few to accommodate the posted values. check that